# Finding area of shaded region on graph

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analytic-geometry, area

With the three equations provided, I can find the coordinates of intersection. However, I have no idea how to find the height as there isnt any right angles. The graph is apparently a triangle, how could I possibly find its area?[image]

Comment: Heron's formula comes immediately to mind. Google it. Also Google `cross product area`. Alternatively find the $x$-intercept of the line whose equation is given, and use that as your "base".

Comment: If you've found all the intersections, make use of [**shoelace formula**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoelace_formula)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With tools that you will probably already be familiar with:

The $x$-axis divides your triangle into two triangles whose common base you can find by computing the $x$-intercept of one of the lines.

Remember that "half the height times the base" is not only for right triangles, but for *any* triangle where you know (or can find) a base and the height perpendicular to it.